# HTTP Basic Authentication - Password only, no username?

Tags: html, authentication, azure, passwords

I am trying to connect to a Windows Azure Mobile Service. I can call an endpoint via browser, but I am getting prompted to enter username and password. I enter my 'Application Key' as password, but leave the username blank and from then on it works fine.

Is there any way of calling the endpoint without entering the password? Normally I would try:

> http://username:password@domainname.com

But as there is no username, the following does not work:

> http://:password@domainname.com

What can I do? the reason behind this is, that I do not want to use the Mobile Services SDK.

Comment: :password work for http auth. you can check here: https://skovpen.org/tst/

Comment: https://username:password@skovpen.org/tst/ works, but https://:password@skovpen.org/tst/ does not I am afraid

Comment: You're a genius, seems to be the only browser it works. But I assume that it works now from any client as well if I send a request like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following URL works fine in Chrome:

> http://:password@domainname.com

Firefox and Internet Explorer won't recognize the format.

So if you are trying to use Windows Azure Mobile Services, there's no need to use the Azure  Mobile SDK, the above works fine.